# Laravel going through hasOne to get attributes

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have the following models.

- `Player`

  - (`hasMany(Monster::class)`)
- `Monster`

  - `hasOne(MonsterSpecies::class,'id','species_id')`
  - `hasOne(MonsterColor::class,'id','color_id')`)
- `MonsterSpecies`
- `MonsterColor`

  - (Both pretty much empty, just `public $timestamps = false;`)

Then, after seeding, in `php artisan tinker` I select one player:

`$player = Player::all()->first();`

It works. Then I check the monsters.

```php
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#3561
     all: [
       App\Models\Monster {#3569
         id: 1,
         created_at: "2021-12-09 16:39:29",
         updated_at: "2021-12-09 16:39:29",
         name: "Alberto Mills",
         level: 17,
         currHealth: 68,
         maxHealth: 76,
         strength: 42,
         defense: 29,
         movement: 13,
         species: 28,
         color: 34,
         player_id: 1,
       },
       App\Models\Monster {#4505
         id: 2,
         created_at: "2021-12-09 16:39:29",
         updated_at: "2021-12-09 16:39:29",
         name: "Darlene Price",
         level: 9,
         currHealth: 16,
         maxHealth: 32,
         strength: 44,
         defense: 19,
         movement: 61,
         species: 28,
         color: 34,
         player_id: 1,
       },
     ],
   }
```

Then `$player->monster->get(0)->color;`

```php
 App\Models\MonsterColor {#4508
     id: 34,
     name: "Red_Blue",
   }
```

Now I believe I can add `getSpeciesAttribute()` and `getSpeciesAttribute()` to directly return the name or maybe do something like:

```
public function getSpeciesAttribute($value)
{
    $colors = explode("_",$value->name); // I don't know if this is how I get the name
    $out = "Your monster's color is ";
    if (count($colors) > 1) {
        $out .= "a mesh of " . implode(", ",array_slice($colors, 0, -1)) . " and ";
    }
    $out .= array_pop($colors);
    return $out;
}
```

But I don't know how to access the `name` attribute of `MonsterColor`.

## Edit:

Here's the Monster, MonsterColor and MonsterSpecies models.

```php
class Monster extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'level',
        'currHealth',
        'maxHealth',
        'strength',
        'defense',
        'movement',
        'species',
        'color'
    ];

    public function player()
    {
       return $this->belongsTo(Player::class);
    }

    public function species()
    {
       return $this->hasOne(MonsterSpecies::class,'id','species_id');
    }

    public function color()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(MonsterColor::class,'id','color_id');
    }

    public function getSpeciesAttribute()
    {
        return $this->species->name;
    }

    public function getColorAttribute()
    {
        return $this->color->name;
    }
}

class MonsterColor extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public $timestamps = false;
}

class MonsterSpecies extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

Comment: What model is `getSpeciesAttribute` on?

Comment: @Andy on Monster, updated OP with the Monster class.

Comment: It looks like what you have in your edit should work.. are you getting some kind of error or unexpected behavior? If I had to guess, I would think you are going to run into problems having a relationship and an attribute with the same name.

Comment: may be it will work for him, He wants all attributes i think with joining in laravel i guess `Monster::with("player")->with("species")->with("color")->get(); `


`Player::with("monster",function($e){
   $e->with("species")->with("color")->get();
});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The accessor `getColorAttribute()` creates a "virtual" `color` property on the model class. But you also have a relationship method called `color()`. Relationship methods also create virtual properties, which you are trying to access with `$this->color`.

So the problem is simply one of colliding names. Easiest solution would be to rename the accessor to something else.

The problem is the same with your other accessor, and also they don't accept parameters; they're accessed as properties so there's no way to pass one.

```php
public function getColorNameAttribute()
{
    return $this->color->name;
}

public function getSpeciesDescriptionAttribute()
{
    $colors = explode("_", $this->color->name);
    return sprintf(
        "Your monster's color is %s",
        implode(" and ", $colors)
    );
}
```

Now you can access these via `$player->monsters[0]->color_name` or `$player->monsters[0]->species_description`.

---

A couple of other notes:

- you shouldn't have `color` and `species` in `$fillable` as they aren't database columns
- you don't need to declare column names in relationship methods (e.g. `$this->hasOne(MonsterColor::class,'id','color_id')`) unless they are non-standard – yours are not
- if a relationship returns a collection it should be named with a plural (i.e. not `$player->monster` as in your question)
- do look into [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) of relationships.

Comment: Color and species will be selectable by the player when creating a monster and they are database columns.

If I take the column names off the relationship method I get `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'monster_colors.monster_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `monster_colors` where `monster_colors`.`monster_id` = 1 and `monster_colors`.`monster_id` is not null limit 1`.

I renamed to `getSpeciesNameAttribute` and `getColorNameAttribute` and I can access them with `$player->monsters->get(0)->colorName` and `$player->monsters->get(0)->color_name`.

Comment: Question, would it be cleaner/preferred to make the relationship methods `MonsterSpecies` and `MonsterColor` and the accessors `getSpeciesAttribute` and `getColorAttribute`, since then `$monster->MonsterSpecies` actually returns a `MonsterSpecies` model and `$monster->species` simply returns the name??

Comment: That error means your species and color relations should be `belongsTo`, not `hasOne`. See https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many. Name them whatever makes the most sense for you, there are no hard and fast rules. There are conventions though, e.g. when accessing properties, snake case is usually used (`$monster->monster_species`)

Comment: Just for clarity I would also add `public function monsters() { return $this->hasMany(Monster::class);`}` on both the `MonsterSpecies` and `MonsterColor` models. Even if never used, it can be a good sanity check. Seeing `hasMany` on one side of the relationship, you know the other side should be `belongsTo`.